# $f$ has the form $f(x) =ax^2+bx+c$.

Tags: real-analysis

Every differentiable function $f:R \rightarrow R$ with the property that $(2h)f′(x) =f(x+h)−f(x−h)$ for all $x \in R$ and all $h$ has the form $f(x) =ax^2+bx+c$.

I would like to get some help on this one. Taking partial derivatives was an idea, but is that legal?

Comment: Hint: show that: $8h^{3}f'''(x)=f(x+3h)-3f(x+h)+3f(x-h)-f(x-3h)=0$. All derivatives taken with respect to $x$.

Comment: I'm no lawyer, but I think taking partial derivatives is legal in most jurisdictions. Maybe this question is more appropriate for the [Law stackexchange](https://law.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @Floris Claassens I've been trying to figure out your hint for a couple of hours now. Anything further you can say? I tried taking another derivative, and using identities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for all $h$ we have
$$4h^{2} f''(x)=2hf'(x+h)-2hf'(x-h)=f(x+2h)-2f(x)+f(x-2h).$$
Deriving again with respect to $x$ gives
$$8h^{3} f'''(x)=2hf'(x+h)-4hf'(x)+2hf(x-2h)=f(x+3h)-3f(x+h)+3f(x-h)-f(x-3h)$$
Note that $f(x+3h)-f(x-3h)=6hf'(x)$ and $-3f(x+h)+3f(x-h)=-6hf'(x)$, hence 
$$8h^{3} f'''(x)=0.$$
As this holds for all $h$ we find that $f'''(x)=0$ and thus $f(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $f'(x)={1\over2}\bigl(f(x+1)-f(x-1)\bigr)$ for all $x$. Since here
 the RHS  is differentiable it follows that $f'$ is differentiable as well; in fact $f\in C^\infty$. We now differentiate
$2 h f'(x)=f(x+h)-f(x-h)$ two times with respect to $h$ and obtain
$$0=f''(x+h)-f''(x-h)\qquad\forall\,x\quad\forall\, h\ .$$
This implies $f''(u)=f''(v)$ for all $u$ and $v$, i.e., $f''(x)$ is a constant, say $2a$. This in turn implies $f'(x)=2ax+b$ and $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ for constant $a$, $b$, $c$.

Comment: Why did you show the case when $h = 1$? @Christian Blatter

Comment: This was only for the check that $x\mapsto f'(x)$ is differentiable.