# $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(\frac{a+b}{2})$ such function is polynomial of degree less than or equal to two.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, functional-equations

Consider differential function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with the property that for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$   we have 
$$f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(\frac{a+b}{2})$$

Then show that every such function is polynomial of degree less than or equal to two.

i was thinking of applying Roll theorem. but got nowhere.please  provide a hint

Thanks in advanced

Comment: See here:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112546/f-has-the-form-fx-ax2bxc/3112723#comment6415812_3112723

Comment: The given condition is equivalent to saying $f'$ has the mean value property, therefore it must be harmonic, i.e., linear.